# 'Label' does not contain a definition for 'ForeColor'.

Tags: c#, wpf, label, visual-studio-2017

Basically, I have a button, that, when pressed, should change another label's text color. However, whenever I try to run it, I get the error:

> 'Label' does not contain a definition for 'ForeColor' and no extension method 'ForeColor' accepting a first argument 'Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The basic code is:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tlabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

What should I do?

Sorry if the question might be easily fixable but I just recently started with C# and I couldn't find any solutions that fix my problem (or questions that are even similar).

Comment: Don't confuse WPF with Winforms, they are *very* different GUI class libraries.  Be sure to let the IntelliSense popup help you fall in the pit of success, it will fight you tooth and nail to stop you from typing "ForeColor".

Comment: One thing you should be doing in situations like this is going to the documentation for the Label class. After looking over the properties, this would have been fairly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is called `Foreground` and it's a `Brush`, not a `Color`.

```
tlabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

The advantage of using a brush instead of a color is that red is just red, but a `Brush` could be a lot of things. The system brush I showed you is a `SolidColorBrush` -- just red -- but [there are various gradient brushes](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-lineargradientbrush/), [ImageBrushes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx), and so on.

`System.Drawing` is a windows forms namespace, not WPF. `ForeColor` is a windows forms property as well. Make sure the documentation you're looking at is for WPF, not windows forms.